# How to change style of material-UI date picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to apply some margin and change the style of the material-ui-pickers. There is no style section in the documentation.

Here is the link for the datePicker https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage

By inspecting the element I found the class and I need to apply style for that class
I tried the following code but the styles are not applied because rule name root is not valid here

```
const StyledPicker = withStyles({
   root: {
    '& .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton': {
      backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
      borderRadius: 0,
      width: 32,
      height: 32,
      margin: '10 30',
    },
  },
})(DatePicker);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this inside a [makeStyles](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) and `useStyles` inside your component and use it as `className`:

`'& .$MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton': {`

I share room a exeptionnal [link about `material-ui` styles.](https://codeburst.io/my-journey-to-make-styling-with-material-ui-right-6a44f7c68113?source=---------2------------------)

Comment: I tried still not working. The rule name root is not valid here

Comment: I update my answer. Try use a makeStyles and use classes inside your component. The makeStyles API is not supported by everyone